# Error java.lang.stringindexoutofboundsexception string index out of range 11

Tags: java

El programa es encriptar un mensaje utilizando el metodo de cerca

El programa compila bien, pero al momento de introducir una palabra me marca el error de "java.lang.stringindexoutofboundsexception string index out of range: # " este problema ocurre al momento de asignarle el valores al array que esta dentro de el ciclo for,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner sc = null;
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int contador = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    String palabra = " ";
    char arreglo[][] = null;

    System.out.print("Ingrese la palabra a encriptar: ");
    palabra = sc.nextLine();

    arreglo = new char[3][palabra.length()];

    while(contador < palabra.length()) {

        while(i < 3) {

            arreglo[i][j] = palabra.charAt(contador);

            i++;
            j++;
            contador++;

        }

        if(i == 3) {

            for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {

                i--;

                arreglo[i][j] = palabra.charAt(contador);

                j++;
                contador++;

            }

        }

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

se desborda porque le sigues sumando a la variable "j" y esta rebasa el tamaño de palabra.length()

imprime ambas variables antes de que le insertes el valor y te daras cuenta.

```
System.out.println(i + "-" + j);
arreglo[i][j] = palabra.charAt(contador);
```